# 1server 2ips => 2nameservers possible?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, nameserver, ns-record

I rented a vServer with 2 ip addresses. I installed ISPConfig on it and I am now configuring the server. Now I am having a lot of troubles in configuring the DNS Zones to make my nameservers work.

I am not a network specialist, that's why I hope that someone here can answer my question.

Is it possible on one server with two ips to set-up two working nameservers?

Using www.dnssy.com to test my site, the last result I achieved was as follows:

> Your NS records at your nameservers are:
>
> ns2.mydomain.ch reported:
>
> ns1.mydomain.ch reported:
>   ns1.mydomain.ch [100.100.100.101] TTL 86400
>   ns2.mydomain.ch [100.100.100.102] TTL 86400

that's not what I want. I would like the second ip to go under my ns2

If you want additional information, just ask in a comment and I will then edit this post as fast as possible :)

Comment: Putting them both on the same server sort of half-defeats the purpose of having two of them in the first place.

Comment: As Ignacio already said: It is possible, but **don't** do it.

Comment: I know, that it is against the purpose of ns's, but the reason I would like to do it is because for some ISP's, you MUST give 2 NS's if you want to set-up a domain. Still wondering how to achieve this (its for private use, if i will ever use it commercially [or one of my websites has success :P], i will ofc rent a 2nd server 2 mirror it and use the 2nd NS there

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to skirt the 2 NS requirement of many TLDs, you're much better off just setting up the server as one, then setting up a free secondary service (like afraid.org or buddyns.com).

If you think that you need two NS to run two different domains, then many domains can be run off a single DNS Server. If your domain has multiple name servers then all name servers should return the full list. Looks like you have `ns1.mydomain.ch` setup correctly, but the other server is apparently returning nothing (should be returning the same thing as the first server).

If you're trying to do something else, just stop right now, you're doing it wrong.